# Open Office plot graph of a single column

Tags: openoffice

I have a an spreadsheet of a questionnaire I conducted. Each column represents a multiple choice question and the values are the answers selected by each participant. Therefore each column has repeated values. Example :

```
**What is your favourite website?**
stackoverflow
superuser
superuser
stackoverflow
serverfault
```

I want a chart that compares the amount of times a value is repeated, preferably in percentage. Something like this:

[image: chart]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function COUNTIF. So you do another table, like:

```
 stackoverflow | =COUNTIF(range of your survey, previous column)
 superuser     | =COUNTIF(range of your survey, previous column)
 serverfault   | =COUNTIF(range of your survey, previous column)
```

You will obtain something like:

```
stackoverflow  | 2
superuser      | 2
serverfault    | 1
```

Which is what you wnt